# Did Mordechei ever tell Esther she was allowed to reveal her nationality?

Tags: purim, megillat-esther, esther--the-woman, mordechai

Mordechai had told Esther that she can't reveal her nationality and Esther took that very seriously. Did he tell her that she was suddently allowed to reveal her nationality at the second party or did Esther decide that herself?

To clarify:I'm looking for an explicit source (Midrash, Gemara, etc.) that says that Mordechai told her she can tell her nationality at some point. There are numerous ways that she could have tried to get the king to change his mind without revealing her nationality if that had been necessary.

Comment: Who says this was a formal issur that he had to repeal?  How did he even have the authority to make issurim like this?  Maybe it was just good advice and at this point it wasn't relevant anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a source.
Its a Pesikta Rabsi

> פסיקתא זוטרתא (לקח טוב) אסתר ד:ח ד"ה ואת פתשגן - עד עתה אין אסתר מגדת, מעתה נתן לה רשות להודיע שהיא יהודית, שנאמר על עמה, וכן אמרה אסתר כי נמכרנו אני ועמי:
>
> Pesikta Rabsi (Lekach Tov) 4:8 - Until now Esther didn't reveal her nationality, not he (Mordechai) gave her permission to reveal that she is Jewish, and that's what (why) Esther said "For I and my nation have been sold."